ASP.NET MVC - unwanted characters in user input
I am developing ASP.NET MVC application, which is basically information system. We have a problem, that users of the application sometimes copy something from the email or something else into a user input in the app and inside of the copied text might have been some unwanted characters. I have seen for instance byte-order mark (BOM) - U+FEFF or 0x00 char. These are characters that are not visible while copying.
We recently added whitelisting validation into the application on all of the user input to solve that problem but another problem appeared. Users still sometimes copy text from emails or even from old records, where those unwanted characters might still be because it was created before the validation was implemented. Now there are some bug reports that validation won't let them save the record with the copied text but they obviously don't know that there are some invisible characters that are not wanted.
My question is if there is a nice solution to this. Whether we need to show a more describing validation message? Or whether we should implement some kind of truncating those unwanted characters? (Problem with truncating is that we don't know what different characters might it be and we also don't want to truncate something important from the input) Or just something else?
Disclaimer: I don't think we might force users to use the application different way.
Besides implementing whitelisting validations I have tried googling how other people deal with that. I was not lucky with googling.

I think a clear validation message like 'invalid invisible characters' will not satisfy the user. What the user is supposed to do when encountering this error message ?
I suggest you a client validation less restrictive and on the server side a text parsing played before server validation occurs.

Using a white list is (by default) the appropriate first step, since it's the most secure solution. You don't write exactly why you need to prevent those invisible characters, but security would be an appropriate motivation.
What remains is really a set of socio-technical problems, rather than strictly technical. Exactly how you address those, you'll have to work out with users, product managers etc.
Since you already have a white list, it ought to be possible to strip all existing data of 'illegal' bytes. You could either go through the entire data store as a batch job, and do it once and for all. Alternatively, you could strip data on the fly, before you actually print it on user interfaces. This should, at least, prevent further copy-paste problems when users copy and paste from existing data.
This doesn't, however, address the issue where users ostensibly copy and paste from emails or other external data sources.
Here, you may consider at least two options:

Prevent users from adding data with illegal bytes in them. As I understand it, that's what you already do.
Automatically strip illegal bytes from the input. You can do this silently, or notify users that you've automatically cleaned the data.

If neither of these options are acceptable, you may be able to go through bug reports in order to figure out exactly which invisible characters tend to cause problems, and then handle these explicitly in some way. Again, the problem isn't strictly technical, but rather a question of user experience (UX) design. These sorts of problems sometimes require some trial and error before you arrive at a UX design that most users find understandable.
